# Why is my nested attributes form not working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a model called profile that has_many jobs.  I am using the cocoon gem in order to allow users to make a profile, and then on a separate page make as many jobs as they'd like.  The profile form is working fine.  The job form, however, doesn't seem to actually be creating the jobs.  Since a user needs to fill out a profile form before they can fill out a jobs form, by the time they get to the jobs form, it will automatically go to the update action in the profiles controller instead of the create.  I'm pretty sure the problem is in the profiles controller.  Here is the profiles controller:

```
def new
    if current_user.profile
        redirect_to edit_profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
    else
        @profile = Profile.new
    end
end


def create
    @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
    @profile.save
    if current_user.profile.invalid?
        render :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    else
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
    end
end

def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
end


def update
    #if current_user.profile.jobs.any?
        @profile_save = current_user.profile.update_attributes(profile_params)

        if current_user.profile.invalid?
            @profile = current_user.profile
            render :edit, :status => :unprocessable_entity
        else
            redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
        end
end

private
def profile_params
      params.fetch(:profile, {}).permit(:title, 
            :category, :description, :state, :zip_code, :rate,
            jobs_attributes: [:firm, :position, :category, :description,
            :begin, :end, :_destroy])
end
```

I use fetch instead of require because otherwise I received an error saying the profile was not found.  Here is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <h3> Jobs </h3>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :jobs do |job| %>
     <%= render 'job_fields', :f => job %>
       <% end %>
     <%= link_to_add_association 'add job', f, :jobs %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the job_fields partial:

```
.nested-fields
 <%= f.input :firm, label: "Firm" %> <br>
  <%= f.input :position, label: "Position" %> <br>
  <%= f.input :category, label: "Category"%><br>
  <%= f.input :begin, label: "Beginning", collection: 1960..2013 %><br>
  <%= f.input :end, label: "End", collection: 1960..2013 %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Description"%><br>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove task", f %>
```

The problem could also be that I translated from HAML to ERB and I think I did it incorrectly.

Also, all profiles actually belong to a user, but i don't think that should make a difference.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you want to call the `create` method for `Jobs`, you'll need to modify your form to explicitly use the `post` method.  Something like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile, :url => new_jobs_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <h3> Jobs </h3>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :jobs do |job| %>
     <%= render 'job_fields', :f => job %>
       <% end %>
     <%= link_to_add_association 'add job', f, :jobs %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```